# External Hard Drive usable in Windows, but not even showing in System Information on Mac

Tags: hard-drive, mac, usb, external-hard-drive

My external WD Passport USB has been working absolutely fine in Windows 10, but has not been showing recently in my Mac.

I've force formatted the Hard Drive to exFAT in Windows, and is still working and usable.

But on my Macbook Pro (MacOS High Sierra), the drive isn't visible in diskutil, Disk Utility or even System Information (The USB Bus isn't showing).

The drive still spins, and the activity light is constant - but as far as I can tell it looks dead.

This is a new one for me, and I have no idea on what to do next and everything points to the drive being healthy.

UPDATE: Screenshot of USB device tree, with two external USB devices plugged in (The Elements 25A2 is another WD Drive):

[image: System Information USB Device Bus]

Comment: If the USB bus isn't showing, you've got other problems, since it should be showing even if no devices are connected. Can you take a screenshot of the device tree and post it here?

Comment: @JMY1000 I've updated the original question.

Comment: It could be a power draw issue, but I find that extremely unlikely and you should (in theory) get a warning if that's the case. I'm really not sure. You may also want to try apple.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

If the USB connector it self is not even showing up in the System Information app there is a likely a problem with the USB port,  or the USB versions are incompatible.   i.e.  The drive is say USB-3 but the computer only supports USB-2, or vice versa.   Do other things work when plugged into the USB port(s) in question?

Comment: The USB Port itself is fine, as you can see in the updated screenshot, another WD drive works fine when it's plugged in. It's just this one that doesn't show.